# Взаимодействие Activities

Tags: activity, android, android-intent

Здравствуйте! У меня имеются 3 `Activity`, пусть `Activity` `А` - главное `Activity`, из которого вызываются `B` и `C` `Activity`. B - Activity с настройками, а `C` - `Activity` с основными действиями. Мне необходимо в `B` реализовать `ToggleButton`, который отвечает за то, будет ли вибрировать устройство, если нажимать кнопки в `C`. Таким образом, необходимо связать `B` и `C`. Если использовать `Intent`, то там необходимо вызывать метод `StartActivity(Intent)/StartActivityForResult(Intent)`. Отсюда следует, что при нажатии на `ToggleButton` в `B` сразу вызовется `C`. А мне это ненужно. Мне нужно, чтобы при нажатии на `ToggleButton` "что-то где-то" запомнилось, а потом при вызове `C` это "что-то где-то" дало о себе знать, и устройство вибрировало. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как решить эту проблему. Может есть другой способ?

Comment: Вообще не вижу связи между изменением ToggleButton и запуском Activity.

Comment: Ведь при  работе с intents необходимо вызывать эти самые методы или можно как-то по-другому?

Comment: Проблема решена. Спасибо.

Comment: @Alex Les, я вообще не понял, зачем Вам там использовать Intent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А SharedPreferences не вариант?http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html

Comment: Вспомнил про этот, когда уже создал тему, поторопился. Спасибо